# Sorting by unique values of multiple fields in UNIX shell script

Tags: c, unix, sorting, unique, field

I am new to unix and would like to be able to do the following but am unsure how.

Take a text file with lines like:

```
TR=P567;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=worcester
TR=P567;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=lowell
TR=P567;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=worcester
TR=P234;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=lowell
TR=P234;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=lowell
TR=P234;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=worcester
```

And output this:

```
TR=P567;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=worcester
TR=P567;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=lowell
TR=P234;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=lowell
TR=P234;dir=o;day=su;TI=12:10;stn=westborough;Line=worcester
```

I would like the script to be able to find all all the lines for each TR value that have a unique Line value.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include (1) sample input, (2) sample output, and (3) the code that you have so far? Also -- why do you want to do this in C? It seems like it would be simpler to use the common GNU utilities, `grep` and `sort` and `sed` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are apparently O.K. with randomly choosing among the values for `dir`, `day`, `TI`, and `stn`, you can write:

```
sort -u -t ';' -k 1,1 -k 6,6 -s < input_file > output_file
```

Explanation:

- The `sort` utility, "sort lines of text files", lets you sort/compare/merge lines from files. (See [the GNU Coreutils documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation).)
- The `-u` or `--unique` option, "output only the first of an equal run", tells `sort` that if two input-lines are equal, then you only want one of them.
- The `-k POS[,POS2]` or `--key=POS1[,POS2]` option, "start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)", tells `sort` where the "keys" are that we want to sort by. In our case, `-k 1,1` means that one key consists of the first field (from field `1` through field `1`), and `-k 6,6` means that one key consists of the sixth field (from field `6` through field `6`).
- The `-t SEP` or `--field-separator=SEP` option tells `sort` that we want to use `SEP` — in our case, `';'` — to separate and count fields. (Otherwise, it would think that fields are separated by whitespace, and in our case, it would treat the entire line as a single field.)
- The `-s` or `--stabilize` option, "stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison", tells `sort` that we *only* want to compare lines in the way that we've specified; if two lines have the same above-defined "keys", then they're considered equivalent, even if they differ in other respects. Since we're using `-u`, that means that means that one of them will be discarded. (If we weren't using `-u`, it would just mean that `sort` wouldn't reorder them with respect to each other.)

Comment: i only want unique combinations of the first and sixth fields, I don't  want the middle values to factor in

Comment: @AdamWilner: I don't understand what you mean: your example output still includes those middle values. Are you saying that, if the same `TR` and `Line` appear twice, but with different values of `day`, then you want one of the values of `day` to be randomly discarded?

Comment: Yes more or less. I want to be left with only lines with with a unique combination of TR and Line. The values in the middle should not be factored in to whether the line is unique or not. They happen to be the same in this chunk of code but I have a text file with over 8000 lines and  they vary from line to line

Comment: I can't restrain a "me too!" comment :)

That one liner is really brilliant, and easily adaptable for my needs. Awesome.