# Selecting unique lines based on two columns

Tags: unix, awk

I've been trying to figure out a way to select lines that are unique based on the values of two columns. For example, here is a sample/example of my file:

```
chr1    10    12
chr1    10    12
chr1    10    11
chr1    9    12
chr2    15    20
```

And this is what I want my output to look like:

```
chr1    10    12
chr1    10    11
chr1    9    12
chr2    15    20
```

I've tried to use this code because I like how it doesn't mess with the order of my file:

```
awk -F"\t" '!_[$2]++' SNP_positions.txt > SNP_positions_uniq.txt
```

However, it only captures unique features of one column. Is there a way to edit this to make it work for two columns?

Comment: you mention two columns but there are three in your file. Which ones should be considered? Give a more generic example if possible. Your current approach works for the given file, so there may be something else.

Comment: I want to find lines that have unique values in both column two and three. If I used the code above my output would not give me the 3rd line in my output (chr1 122332 130204). I'll edit to make it more simple

Comment: Whoever told you to use `_` as a variable name is an idiot, do not listen to them any more. We all know that single-letter variable names are best avoided in general as they do nothing to improve the clarity of your code, but using something that's not even a letter is just ridiculous.

Comment: @cosmictypist how to run this query in mysql. i have the same problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can perfectly use an index that uses more than one field for the array elements:

```
awk -F"\t" '!seen[$2, $3]++' file
```

In this case we use `$2, $3` as index. This way, we will get all different elements of the tuples `($2, $3)`.

Comment: If I wanted to use this for all three columns would the code look like this: `awk -F"\t" '!uniq[$1 FS $3]++' file` or `awk -F"\t" '!uniq[$1 FS $2 FS $3]++' file'`

Comment: @christylynn002 If you want to use the full line it is faster to say `uniq[$0]`. If you want three out of more, `uniq[$1 FS $2 FS $3]`. Note we use `FS` to prevent `2\tab3` match a line being `2 3`.

Comment: @jaypalsingh note that the `,` in an array index is not the same as a `,` in a print statement. The former gets the value of `SUBSEP` (a control char by default) while the latter gets the value of `OFS` (a space by default).

Answer (score 3):

The `awk` solution provided is great and fast, but I came here myself looking for the `sort` solution, which is probably slower in almost all cases:

```
cat file | sort -u -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -s
```

I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12546627/778533

Comment: You can speed this up by writing `LC_ALL=C sort -S70% -u -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -s`