# How to get the file with unique combination of columns of file using shell script command

Tags: perl, shell

I want to get the unique combination of the 2nd, 7th, and 8th columns

```
IGA US TESTFEEDSystem memory2255935216
```

It should display the entire row of the file

Here is some example data

```
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:02:31||System memory|2255935216|4294967295|4294967295|300
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:04:21||MEMPOOL_DMA|75432384|260292160|260215120|300
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:04:27||MEMPOOL_GLOBAL_SHARED|352552672|4294967295|4294967295|300
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:07:31||System memory|2255935216|4294967295|4294967295|300
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:09:15||MEMPOOL_DMA_ALT1|63314848|272409696|272409600|300
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:09:21||MEMPOOL_DMA|75432384|260292160|260215120|300
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:09:27||MEMPOOL_GLOBAL_SHARED|352552672|4294967295|4294967295|300
```

Comment: it should search for combination of 2,6,7  and display those lines of files  only

Comment: Well, the linked question handles the case of two fields, so you can just change the field separator to a pipe character `-F'|'` and use `[$2,$6,$7]` instead of `[$2,$3]` in the accepted answer.

Comment: @TomFenech: I think the use of *“unique”* here is misleading. The [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895396/selecting-unique-lines-based-on-two-columns) asks for all records that are distinct according to a subset of the columns. I believe the OP here is asking for a way to find all lines in the file with the *specific values* `IGA US TESTFEED`, `System memory` and `2255935216` for columns 2, 7 and 8. We need clarification before this question should be closed

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do as you ask

```
perl -aF'\|' -ne 'print if "@F[1,6,7]" eq "IGA US TESTFEED System memory 2255935216"' myfile.txt
```

#### output

```
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:02:31||System memory|2255935216|4294967295|4294967295|300
C|IGA US TESTFEED|bld-af-y1-dhe.boulder.ibm.com|02/21/2016|00:07:31||System memory|2255935216|4294967295|4294967295|300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x="IGA US TESTFEED"; 
y="System memory"; 
z="2255935216"; 
grep ".*|$x|.*|.*|.*|.*|$y|$z|.*" file
```

Comment: Can u replace the static column value into dynamic column count, like   :   grep ".*|$2|.*|.*|.*|.*|$6|$7|.*" 'M02232016.IGA-US-TESTFEED.dat',     Correct me the syntax