# AWK script for series of duplicates

Tags: awk

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Original Sample Data in File1:

```
0011,ABC,134,E,E
0034,GGG,234,I,E
0011,ABC,135,I,E
8721,KOO,832,E,E
0011,ABC,136,E,E
0122,DEF,412,E,E
0076,HDD,234,E,E
0122,DEF,422,E,E
0099,CCC,633,I,E
0873,JJJ,352,I,E
0099,CCC,693,E,E
0100,FER,533,E,E
9213,TRE,002,E,E
9213,DWJ,024,O,E
0100,FER,543,O,E
1256,CCC,902,C,E
0100,FER,583,P,E
0323,SWE,745,I,E
```

So i have sorted and filtered my csv files with duplicate entries (already removed single records):

```
sort file1|awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } { c[$1]++; l[$1,c[$1]]=$0 } END { for (i in c) { if (c[i] > 1) for (j = 1; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] } }' file1 > file2
```

File 2 output:

```
0100,FER,533,E,E
0100,FER,543,O,E
0100,FER,583,P,E
0099,CCC,633,I,E
0099,CCC,693,E,E
0122,DEF,412,E,E
0122,DEF,422,E,E
9213,TRE,002,E,E
9213,DWJ,024,O,E
0011,ABC,134,E,E
0011,ABC,135,I,E
0011,ABC,136,E,E
```

I'm only trying to get duplicate sets where COL4 = I, in which case keep all the duplicates in the same set based on COL1 otherwise delete the series.

Desired Output:

```
0011,ABC,134,E,E
0011,ABC,136,E,E
0011,ABC,135,I,E
0099,CCC,693,E,E
0099,CCC,633,I,E
```

Comment: Keeping all your data in memory and only printing in the `END` is pretty wasteful. Just keep a hash of they keys you have seen and print immediately if the key is not already in the hash (and otherwise skip, meaning you don't print anything you have seen before). Changing the key so it looks at the fields you want should be reasonably trivial and probably has multiple duplicates on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: Can you show your sample input?

Comment: @Tiw Presumably the "file 2 output" is representative enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting unique lines based on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895396/selecting-unique-lines-based-on-two-columns)

Comment: @tripleee  Ah, right. It is :)

Comment: @tripleee this is not really a duplicate. The question is: _Print all sets where one or more members of the set have an entry `$4=="I"`. A set is composed of all members with an identical `$1`._

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying -- I didn't understand the OP's exposition of how they defined a "set".

Comment: @tugar, could you please check provided solutions once and let us know on same then?

Comment: Given a second thought, it's still better to show your sample input. Does your `file1` separated with commas, or not?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions! I'll add the original data set and modify the output to be exactly what is needed. Yes, @Tiw it is separated by commas.

Comment: You didn't mention `sort`, and the desired output is a bit different from the sorted order. Do you want the line with "I" always at the end of the sets? since in sort order they are not.

Comment: Updated my answer, check it again. It's based on your own solution.

Comment: @tugar, Can you please check my solution now? It was/is same as your attempt itself with few improvements. Let us know how it goes then.

Answer (score 0):

Finally understood what you mean, what you need you can achieve simply by adding another signal variable, try this pls:

```
awk -F, '$4=="I"{p[$1]} {c[$1]++; l[$1,c[$1]]=$0} END{ for (i in c) { if (c[i] > 1 && i in p) for (j = 1; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] }}' file1 > file2
```

If you want sort first, then this:

```
sort file1 | awk -F, '$4=="I"{p[$1]} {c[$1]++; l[$1,c[$1]]=$0} END{ for (i in c) { if (c[i] > 1 && i in p) for (j = 1; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] }}' > file2
```

With your sample input, it outputs like this:

```
$  awk -F, '$4=="I"{p[$1]} {c[$1]++; l[$1,c[$1]]=$0} END{ for (i in c) { if (c[i] > 1 && i in p) for (j = 1; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] }}' file1
0099,CCC,633,I,E
0099,CCC,693,E,E
0011,ABC,134,E,E
0011,ABC,135,I,E
0011,ABC,136,E,E

## OR ##

$ sort file1 | awk -F, '$4=="I"{p[$1]} {c[$1]++; l[$1,c[$1]]=$0} END{ for (i in c) { if (c[i] > 1 && i in p) for (j = 1; j <= c[i]; j++) print l[i,j] }}'
0099,CCC,633,I,E
0099,CCC,693,E,E
0011,ABC,134,E,E
0011,ABC,135,I,E
0011,ABC,136,E,E
```

Comment: Some white space and parentheses would make that script much clearer. There's several ways `!seen[$1]++||$4=="I"` might be parsed by the reader (and I'm not 100% convinced it's not ambiguous to awk either).

Comment: @KamilCuk , OP used `FS=","`, and the `Desired Output` is space separated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print; next }
$1 != prev { prt() }
{
    recs[$1] = recs[$1] $0 ORS
    tgtCol[$4]
    prev = $1
}
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( "I" in tgtCol ) {
        printf "%s", recs[prev]
    }
    delete tgtCol
    delete recs
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
COL1  COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5
0011  ABC  134  E    E
0011  ABC  135  I    E
0011  ABC  136  E    E
0099  CCC  633  I    E
0099  CCC  693  E    E
```